# Automatic SEO for wordpress

Tags: seo

I know the ultimate seo plugin for seo optimizing seo. But with more that 250 post, and no seo plugin installed, i like to know if there is a plugin that will
1) make the title of the page, the title of the post
2) make the description based on the first paragraph
3) make the keyword meta by parsing the whole post, retreive all the reveland word that are more that 3% occurence, and fill the meta with them

any idea ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

take a look at [WordPress SEO by Yoast](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-seo/) it will cover :

> 1) make the title of the page, the
>   title of the post
>
> 2) make the
>   description based on the first
>   paragraph

as for your #3

> make the keyword meta by parsing the whole post, retrieve all the relevant word that are more that 3% occurrence, and fill the meta with them

I highly doubt you will find a plugin that does that for you, but there are a few like

- [Keyword Density](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/keyword-density/)
- [SEO-Tool - Keyword Density Checker](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/seo-tool-keyword-density-checker/)

which do chack that , so i guess you can use that to update your keywords.

Comment: Honestly, screw the meta keywords. - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RBTBEfd7z_Y.

Comment: For doing SEO automation, I'd highly recommend Slim SEO https://wpslimseo.com

Answer (score 2):

I agree with **Bainternet** on the recommendation of [Yoast's SEO plug-in](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-seo/).  There's absolutely nothing better, and I've tried a lot of them.

That said, your goal of auto-generating the description and keywords is a bit ... misguided.  It's not the direction you want to go.  If you're going to do SEO at all, take the time to do it right and draft a different description and set of keywords for each page and post.  Auto-generation will get you nowhere.  Yoast even has [an article explaining the negative impact](http://yoast.com/meta-description-seo-social/) of such auto-generation when your links and pages start getting used on other sites.

If you're still intent on auto-generation of descriptions, most SEO systems (Yoast's included) will allow you to do that.  Auto-generating keywords is different.

If you're open to a paid solution (not a free plug-in), I recently came across [ClickBump SEO](http://clickbumpengine.com/clickbump-seo/).  You can auto-generate your focus keyword based on the post/page title, and automatically generate a list of highly-rated similar keywords.  If you're already using them in the post's content, it tells you.  If not, you can work them in to maximize your SEO score.

Answer (score 1):

You've identified a lot of requirements.  Although it will need a little initial configuration, I would recommend [Greg's High Performance SEO](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gregs-high-performance-seo/) from the wordpress.org/extend as another alternative. I've used it on a prior version of one of my personal sites.  It will definitely handle your #1 and #2 requirements, plus some other customizations.  I am unaware of any plugin that will handle #3.